# How to coloring textview from Json result

Tags: android, json

I want to set color text view from the Json result (the code below), if statusspp is SPP textcolor is Red, if statusspp is SP2D textcolor is Green. Can you help me?

This is my full code:
Adapter Class

```
public class AdapterSpp extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataSpp> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataSpp current;
    int currentPos=0;

    public AdapterSpp(Context context, List<DataSpp> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_spp, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        DataSpp current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.textSppName.setText(current.getTextSppName());
        myHolder.textType.setText(current.getTextType());
        myHolder.textSize.setText("Uraian : " + current.getTextSize());
        myHolder.textPrice.setText("Rp. " + current.getTextPrice());
        myHolder.textTgl.setText("Tgl.SPP : " + current.getTextTgl());
        myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_light));
        if(current.getTextType().equalsIgnoreCase("SPP")){
            myHolder.textType.setTextColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        } else if(current.getTextType().equalsIgnoreCase("SP2D")){
            myHolder.textType.setTextColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textSppName;
        TextView textSize;
        TextView textType;
        TextView textPrice;
        TextView textTgl;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textSppName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textFishName);
            textSize = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textSize);
            textType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textType);
            textPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
            textTgl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTgl);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}
```

And this my Mainactivity class :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVSpp;
private AdapterSpp mAdapter;

SearchView searchView = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
        new AsyncFetch(query).execute();

    }
}

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;

    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery) {
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("http://ditkeu.unair.ac.id/andro/sp2d-search.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return ("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataSpp> data = new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if (result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Results found for entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            try {


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");


                    DataSpp SppData = new DataSpp();
                    SppData.setTextSppName(json_data.getString("namapenerima"));
                    SppData.setTextSize(json_data.getString("uraianspp"));
                    SppData.setTextType(json_data.getString("statusspp"));
                    SppData.setTextPrice(formatter.format(json_data.getInt("jumlahtotal")));
                    SppData.setTextTgl(json_data.getString("tglsp2d"));
                    data.add(SppData);
                }

                mRVSpp = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
                mAdapter = new AdapterSpp(MainActivity.this, data);
                mRVSpp.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVSpp.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My Custom Adapter :

```
public class DataSpp {

    private String textSppName;
    private String textSize;
    private String textType;
    private String textPrice;
    private String textTgl;

    //getters and setters
public String getTextSppName() {
    return textSppName;
}

public void setTextSppName(String textSppName) {
    this.textSppName = textSppName;
}

public String getTextSize() {
    return textSize;
}

public void setTextSize(String textSize) {
    this.textSize = textSize;
}

public String getTextType() {
    return textType;
}

public void setTextType(String textType) {
    this.textType = textType;
}

public String getTextPrice() {
    return textPrice;
}

public void setTextPrice(String textPrice) {
    this.textPrice = textPrice;
}

public String getTextTgl() {
    return textTgl;
}

public void setTextTgl(String textTgl) {
    this.textTgl = textTgl;
}
```

}

Comment: where you get color exactly and where is your textview?

Comment: above i've given my adapter and mainactivity code..please help

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are showing the text in **TextView**

```
 TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
    if(sppData.statusName.equalsIgnoreCase("SPP"))
    {textView.setTextColor(Color.RED)}
    elseif(sppData.statusName.equalsIgnoreCase("SP2D"))
    {textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)}
```

Comment: yess you right, im showing it to the textview, but textview code is in a adapter class, so sppData can not be read. Any solution sir?

Comment: you need to use a model class for getting the data in your class containing textView, so every time you have a value it will be set in the model class and then you can have the object calling the getter method from the textView class to set the text and implement the condition given above for the textView int the textView class

Comment: **simply create a class with  fields and generate setter and getter method (which can be done easily in android studio)**, then have two objects of the model class in the adapter class and JSON object class, perform the above operation

Comment: actualy im a newbie for java code android, would yo give me a sample code for it.

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter try adding this :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
  DataSpp current=data.get(position);
  myHolder.textSppName.setText(current.SppName);
  myHolder.textSize.setText("Status : " + current.sizeName);
  myHolder.textType.setText("Uraian : " + current.catName);
  myHolder.textPrice.setText("Rp. " + current.price);
  myHolder.textTgl.setText("Tgl.SPP : " + current.tgl);
  myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));

  if(current.statusName.equalsIgnoreCase("SPP"))
  {
    myHolder.textType.setTextColor(Color.RED);
  } else if(current.statusName.equalsIgnoreCase("SP2D"))
  {
    myHolder.textType.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class like this

```
public clas DataSpp{
  private String textSppName;
  private String textSize;
  private String textType;
  private String textPrice;
  private String textTgl;

 //getters and setters
  public String getTextSppName() {
    return textSppName;
  }

  public void setTextSppName(String textSppName) {
    this.textSppName = textSppName;
  }

  public String getTextSize() {
    return textSize;
  }

  public void setTextSize(String textSize) {
    this.textSize = textSize;
  }

  public String getTextType() {
    return textType;
  }

  public void setTextType(String textType) {
    this.textType = textType;
  }

  public String getTextPrice() {
    return textPrice;
  }

  public void setTextPrice(String textPrice) {
    this.textPrice = textPrice;
  }

  public String getTextTgl() {
    return textTgl;
  }

  public void setTextTgl(String textTgl) {
    this.textTgl = textTgl;
  }
}
```

In your json response

```
DataSpp SppData = new DataSpp();
sppData.setTextSppName(json_data.getString("namapenerima");
sppData.setTextSize(json_data.getString("uraianspp");
sppData.setTextType(json_data.getString("statusspp");
sppData.setTextPrice(formatter.format(json_data.getInt("jumlahtotal")));
sppData.setTextTgl(json_data.getString("tglspp");
```

In your on BindViewHolder after setting values

```
if(current.textSppName.equalsIgnoreCase("SPP")){
    myHolder.textType.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else if(current.textSppName.equalsIgnoreCase("SP2D")){
    myHolder.textType.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: i've done Jack, but still textSppName doesnt appear, 
here my code :

Comment: Check your response first.Post your Json response also.

Comment: @RizkiDeddySusanto: can u please post your response you are getting after calling this [link](http://ditkeu.unair.ac.id/andro/sp2d-search.php)